# Why post increment to value of a variable by pointer variable (*variablePointer++) returns garbage value?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, post-increment

I'm just playing around pre/post increment/decrement in `C` language. In the program below, everything works fine with variable `var`. But increments to the pointer variable `*varAddress++` return garbage value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    int var = 1;
    int *varAddress = &var;
    printf("Value befor pre increment %d\n",*varAddress);
    ++*varAddress;
    printf("Value after pre increment %d\n",*varAddress);
    printf("Value befor post increment %d\n",*varAddress);
    *varAddress++;
    printf("Value after post increment %d\n",*varAddress);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Value befor pre increment 1
Value after pre increment 2
Value befor post increment 2
Value after post increment 1606416400
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Where do you think the pointer points after the increment? What value were you expecting the pointee to have?

Comment: If you'd written `(*varAddress)++`, you'd have a satisfactory result, though perhaps less of a lesson learned.

Comment: Note: you ask about "*increments to the pointer variable*", so I assumed you know you're incrementing the pointer, not the pointee, i.e. you already knew how the operator precedence worked. So it turns out you didn't think you were incrementing the pointer at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), suffix increment has higher precedence than indirection operator, so `*varAddress++` is equivalent as:

```
*(varAddress++);
```

which will increase the pointer itself, then point to memory unallocated somewhere else, that's why `*varAddress` will return garbage value (this is UB).

You might want:

```
(*varAddress)++;
```

Answer (score 2):

`++` has higher precedence than `*` so by doing `*varAddress++` you are moving a pointer to some un-owned location and trying to dereference it, which will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, `*varAddress++` increment `varAddress` instead of what it points to.

Comment: Yes .. because of higher precedence

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
char arr[] ="abcd";
char *p=arr,*q=arr;
char k,temp;
temp = *p++; /* here first it assigns value present in address which
is hold by p and then p points to next address.*/
k = ++*q;/*here increments the value present in address which is 
hold by q and assigns to k and also stores the incremented value in the same 
address location. that why *q will get 'h'.*/
printf("k is %c\n",k); //output: k is h
printf("temp is %c\n",temp);//output: temp is g
printf("*p is %c\n",*p);//output: *p is e
printf("*q is %c",*q);//output: *q is h
}
```